# Source maps not generated with simple webpack config

Tags: webpack

I'm unable to get source maps generated for a simple React app that consists of a single component defined using JSX. I'm compiling my app by running `webpack -d -w` and I'm serving the app with nodemon. I've tried various source map tools but I'm not having any luck. Has anyone seen this before? I've also tried setting the sourceMap name in the output and, while a file is generated, it doesn't seem to work when debugging as my errors still point to my bundle.

Here is my config:

```html
module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: './js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    //loaders
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader',
            query : { presets: ['react', 'es2015']}
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

and here is my package.json

```html
{
  "name": "relay_tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "babel-node --presets react,es2015 server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this config that you pasted is for development environment, try to use `eval-source-map` or `eval`. More information [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool)

Comment: So I tried eval-source-map and eval and it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I did and it still does not generate any source maps.